# Casting managed arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, clr, managed

Using an unmanaged Byte array I can insert or extract UInt32 integers using casting like this:-

```
                Byte contents[1024];
                heightwidth = 0x12345678;
                ((UINT32*)&contents)[0] = heightwidth;
                heightwidth=((UINT32*)&contents)[4];
```

How can I do this with a managed Byte array please?

Comment: You can use pin_ptr for the same kind of hack.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
std::array<Byte, 1024>  contA;

heightwidth = 0x12345678;
((UINT32*)contA.data())[0] = heightwidth;
heightwidth=((UINT32*)contA.data())[4];
```

?

Comment: I am using an array of the type array<Byte>^ contents = gcnew array<Byte>(1024) as I am trying not to use std:: functions.